# Are these quartics polynomials having a real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, quadratics, graphing-functions, quartics

I just want some help on some of these equations below to confirm whether they are polynomials having a real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots?
\begin{align}
p(x)&=\frac{1}{3}(2x-6x+1)(x+2)(x-3)(x+3)\\
p(x)&=(x^2-2x+5)(3x-2)(x+1)
\end{align}
Also, after graphing, I noticed that the latter polynomial has only one turning point and no points of inflection compared to previous quartics which number of turning points was degree $n-1$ and the number of points of inflection was $n-2$.
What could be the reason behind this?
Thank you for considering this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question, using MathJax or Latex, to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something but why did you write a factor of $2x-6+1$?

Comment: So now you have a factor of $2x-6x+1$

Comment: In your second example you have a factorisation. What can you say about the factors? What do you know about the relationship between the factors of a polynomial and its roots?

Comment: @fundamentalform thank you for mathjaxing the equations, I'm really new here and still trying to figure out how to write equations with mathjax. And yes, I've corrected the factor to 2−6+1.

Comment: @MarkBennet When graphed, because these are in factored form, as the roots are the solutions plotted on the x-axis, so then, the number of factors or roots in the equations determine the number of points of inflection and turning points, not just the degree itself? For example, the first one has four factors so the number of turning points are 3 and the number of points of inflection are 2, and in the second, the number of turning points are 1 and the points of inflection are zero. Is this correct? Could this be said for any given factored polynomial?

Comment: Ok, that's no problem you have time to learn it! On the typesetting, why have you written that, why not just $1-4x$?

Comment: @fundamentalform ohhhh, I see, no wonder it showed the same characteristic as a polynomial with four distinct linear factors! Do you have any ideas of quartics with a real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots? I kinda get the complex conjugate root theorem being {(a+bi)(a-bi)} so then could I choose any number and plug them in the form {(ax^2+bi)(ax^2-bi)} or {(a+bi)(a-bi)(a+2bi)(a-2bi)} ? Would it be a quartic with a real quadratic factor and complex conjugate roots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations:

First, a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer (or real, or complex) coefficients has $n$ roots in the complex numbers if you count with multiplicity. If the coefficients are real (including rational or integer coefficients), the complex roots (roots which are not real numbers) come in complex conjugate pairs.

Suppose we have (in the factorisation of a polynomial with real coefficients) the root $x=a+bi$. Then its complex conjugate $x=a-bi$ will also be a root. This can be shown various ways, including by direct substitution in the equation and examining real and imaginary parts. In the factorisation into complex numbers these roots will give the linear factors $(x-a-bi)$ and $(x-a+bi)$. In the real numbers you can pair these roots into a quadratic factor $$(x-a-bi)(x-a+bi)=(x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2)$$This is your "real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots".
In the complete factorisation of a polynomial with real coefficients into factors having real coefficients you therefore have two kinds of factor: linear factors, corresponding to real roots, and irreducible quadratic factors corresponding to complex conjugate pairs of roots which appear when you factor over the complex numbers.

In a sense the analysis of turning points and inflexions is a diversion - between two distinct roots there must be a turning point. Between two distinct turning points, there must be an inflexion. But you can have more than one turning point between two roots. Also, if you think about the simple quartic $x^4+1$ this has no real roots and just one turning point. In the case where you have $n$ distinct roots, there must be a turning point between each pair of roots, and an inflexion between each pair of turning points, so the counts will come out as $n-1$ turning points and $n-2$ inflections. But this, as you are learning, is not the only case which occurs.

Comment: Wow, ok, I read this a few more times but I finally get it now ;-; Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, it really makes my day:) Have a good day!

Comment: oh and also, for this to be a quartic, will the factors then be (−−)(−+)

Comment: or {(x^2-ax-bi)(x^2-ax+bi)}

Comment: Is this a good example or loose the x term
{p(x)=(x^2-x+5) (x^2-x-4)}

Comment: @Aileen The factors of a quartic will be four linear factors or two quadratic factors or one quadratic factor with two linear factors. The degrees of the factors add to give the degree of the product. Don't forget that linear factors don't necessarily involve distinct roots so $p(x)=(x-1)^2(x^2+2x+2)$ would also be an example.

Comment: In your product of two quadratics the first is irreducible, while the second $x^2-x-4$ does factorise over the real numbers, as you can check using the quadratic formula. But it is a good example.

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally get it now. This will help so many people, thank you.